# Deleting/overwriting a mounted file on host or in container

Tags: docker

I mount a file on the host to a file inside the docker container:

`-v /var/mydir/myfile.yml:/cotainerdir/myfile.yml`

I expect the file outside the container, to reflect changes made on the file inside the container. For example, when the file inside the container is overwritten, the file on the host also gets overwritten. Or when I delete the file on the host, and overwrite the file inside the container, the file to be created on the host side.

But after deleting the file on the host side, the mount link seems to be broken. Why is this happening?

I use `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}'` and I see the mount relation is there as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're mapping a specific file (identifier|inode) and, when you overwrite|delete it, the mapping is broken.

An alternative approach would be to map a directory that contains the file(s) you're going to be creating|deleting|overwriting:

```sh
docker run .... --volume=var/mydir:/containerdir
```

Then, because the directory will persist, you should (!) be able to create and delete files without issue and changes on the host|container will be reflected corectly.

Comment: That's my guess too. The problem with mapping directory is that the directory can contain files that I don't want to have on the other side.

Comment: I see. I think you're only alternatives are to either map a file and change content but don't delete; or map a directory containing only the files you wish exposed.